# wi-fi на ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, сертификат, dell

много гуглил, но ничего не нашел. Проблема следующая, есть ноутбук, wi-fi на нем работает, я из дома сижу через wi-fi. Хочу на работе подключиться к рабочему wi-fi. Чтобы подключиться к wi-fi нужны сертификаты, они у меня есть(.crt, .crt, .pfx), но где на ubuntu нужно сделать соответствующие настройки, чтобы сеть заработала?

Comment: В при создании нового соединения в защите Wi-Fi выбрать «WPA/WPA2 Enterprise» наверно

Answer (score 0):

да, спасибо за информацию. Написал пост и пошел копаться. Нужно было выбрать безопасность «WPA/WPA2 Enterprise», аутентификация "защищенный EAP(PEAP)" и  далее выбрать выданный сертификат и ввести учетные данные.